# Exporting a gridview to excel in c#

Tags: c#, excel, gridview, export

I have to export an gridview to excel. I am using the following code in button click event funcion :

```
Response.Clear();

Response.Buffer = true;

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=sample.xls");

Response.Charset = "";

Response.ContentType = "app`enter code here`lication/vnd.xls";

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

grdVw.RenderControl(htw);

Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());

Response.End();
```

when I run this a dialog box is opening showing to download an empty XML file. When I tried to debug it, I found that grid has data but it stringWriter is not getting populated. I tried to change the content type to "application/ms-excel" etc. but no result. What is the error in the code and what might be the reason fot stringWriter not getting populated?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't you give a value to the stringwriter when creating the instance. As in `StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(myTextToExport);` As of what happens now, is that the stringWriter doesn't get populated, because nothing is assigned to it I think. But maybe I am mistaken, personally I have no experience with exporting to excel.

Comment: You are rendering a grid to the response, and sending grid's html to the user as an Excel file! This definitely is not what you meant to do!  You should use an excel library, create an excel file, fill it with desired data, and send it as the response.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn : Cant we directly export the data in a grid to excel?

Comment: According to article that Tim has mentioned, your code should work (with the additional code that Tim said in his answer). It seems that the html content of the GridView is a valid Excel file. But I never use such a method. If it was me, I would use a Excel generation library ([CSharpJExcel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/files/CSharpJExcel) for example) to generate the excel file.

Comment: Please see [link](http://csharpektroncmssql.blogspot.ca/2011/12/export-gridview-to-excel-in-aspnet.html)

Comment: @MD.Unicorn: Actually he's not creating a valid _excel-file_ but a html-table stored in a text file with `xls` extension. But it works since excel knows what to do with it. It's really better to create a real excel file, for exampkle with `EPPLus`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `grdVw.RenderControl(htw);` raises an exception that the GridView was not rendered in server form.

Try to execute it in the debugger and i'm fairly sure that you'll see that exception.

You could avoid this exception by overriding [VerifyRenderingInServerForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.verifyrenderinginserverform.aspx)

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    // Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET 
    // server control at run time.  
}
```

See [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1016960.aspx/1?Problem%20with%20GridView%20s%20RenderControl) and [here](http://aspalliance.com/771_CodeSnip_Exporting_GridView_to_Excel).

Comment: The code in question is in C# and you should probably answer the question in C# language.

Comment: Please see [link](http://csharpektroncmssql.blogspot.ca/2011/12/export-gridview-to-excel-in-aspnet.html)

Comment: @TimSchmelter : I have ran in it debugger.  The problem is stringWriter not getting populated.